# How to replace spaces in Java in a efficient and better way

Tags: java, regex

I referred to this link

http://www.crazyforcode.com/replace-spaces-string-%20/

and couldn't find any similar implementation for Java in Stackoverflow

I have implemented a similar logic to replace spaces to `%20` using the below code.

```
String sen="I need to replace all the spaces to %20";
String[] arr = sen.split(" ");
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
for (String str : arr) {
    buff.append(str);
    buff.append("%20");
}
```

But there are many issues with the logic, like it adds `%20` to the last of every sentence. Is there any efficient way of doing this ??

Comment: Why not just do `.replace("%20", " ")` on the string? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Two of those links are about JavaScript. The third claims that it's a C program, but is actually written in Java (and is horribly overcomplicated, and wrong). Maybe try searching for the relevant terms?

Comment: @MattiasBuelens: I have edited my question now.

Comment: Why would you not use a proper XML or HTML encoding class?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils A large part of the reason why the direct flag does not exist is because it'd be misused on questions like this.  [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is for code that is working as intended.  Per `"there are many issues with the logic, like it adds %20 to the last of every sentence"`, this question would be closed as off-topic on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if it were migrated.  Stack Overflow users simply are bad judges of what makes a good [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) post.

Comment: @nhgrif, you're right. I read it as an explanation of why it is inefficient (due to request for an efficient way) not an error as I see is obvious in the code now. Close vote removed - thanks; especially for the obsessive linking to the site.

Answer (score 2):

The best and the most efficient way of doing this is to use a inbuilt library to implement this for you. You can use

```
java.net.URLEncoder
```

and you can find the API here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String- or here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: @user2004685 et al, there's nothing wrong with using the site to document things for yourself or others as long as it meets the guidelines otherwise.

Comment: Yeah but `inbuilt library` has more letters in it than `intrinsic`.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use predefined methods, do the following:

```
String str = "t e s t";
str = str.replace(" ", "%20");
System.out.println(str);
```

This will print out "t%20e%20s%20t".

Answer (score 0):

You can try to substring the output of the StringBuffer.

```
String sen = "I need to replace all the spaces to %20";
String[] arr = sen.split(" ");
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
for (String str : arr) {
    buffer.append(str);
    buffer.append("%20");
}

String bufferString = buffer.toString();
String stringWithoutSpaces = bufferString.substring(0, bufferString.length() - 3);
```

but another more simple solution would be:

```
sen = sen.trim().replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know Java, but if its like c++ a bit, use the fastest method.
It might be old fashioned, but still the fastest.

pseudocode

```
buff = "";
if ( arr.size() > 0 ) {
    buff = arr[0];
    for (int i=1; i<arr.size(); i++)
        buff.append("%20" + arr[i] );
}
```